# RSSI in simulations

Tags: unetstack

I'm about to implement an energy conserving procedure for our modems.
In simulations the RSSI field of RxFrameNtf's is empty and I wonder what way to
best populate it.

I'm running simulations with the half-duplex modem and the BasicAcousticChannel channel models.
The SNR is computed by the acoustic channel and the RxFrameNtf is dispatched by the half-duplex modem right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right that the SNR is not available in the HalfDuplexModem in the current version of UnetStack. There is an open issue to make it available so that `rssi` can be populated in the simulator, and we could prioritize it for the April 2021 release. If you need it before that, we could explore a beta release of the feature for your testing.

Comment: A beta release would be very much appreciated! I need it relatively soon, but I can make a simple temporary solution until then.

Comment: Noted. Will bump up the priority and post once available.

Comment: @moerot We have a beta version for the upcoming UnetStack 3.3.0 now ready, and it includes support for `rssi`. The actual release will be at the beginning of April, but we can make a beta release available to you if you wish to test it. If interested, create an issue on the [unet-contrib](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib) repo, and we can coordinate.